# SSRS Export to Excel with multiple tabs

Tags: reporting-services

I currently have a report with three separate Tablixs A, B, C set so that each one exports to a new Excel tab. When I export the report everything is fine but what I want to do is when I initially render the report I only want to show the results for Tablix B but upon exporting show all three in their relevant tabs. Does anyone know how to do this?

I have tried setting the visible option on the tablix but when I render the report I just end up with a blank page until I click to move on to page 2, where I then see Tablix 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built in export is designed to export the rendered version of the report, so any visible/enabled properties you set on controls will affect both the Report Manager and Exported version.

One solution would be to have 2 RDL's:

A puplic RDL used for viewing in report manager that only has one page showing the Tab 2 data.

You could then have a subscription on a 2nd RDL (not to be run manually in report manager) that saves down or emails the full version you want in .xls format.